# How to extract frames in real time from the MediaStream object returned from the frontend in backend

Tags: javascript, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

is it possible to extract frames in real-time on the backend from a MediaStream object returned from the frontend? something like:- instead of extracting frames from a canvas element in frontend and sending those frames to the backend in real time, can we send just the `stream` instance to the backend and extract frames there in real time until the user stops the recording?

```js
chrome.tabCapture.capture({ audio: false, video: true }, function(stream) {
  // Use the media stream object here
});
```

I am using tabCapture api which returns a `stream`, now I want to send this `MediaStream` instance in real time to the backend and extract frames there and edit something on them in real-time using OpenCV or FFmpeg. is this something technically possible?

One approach I have seen is

```js
chrome.tabCapture.capture({ audio: false, video: true }, function(stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
});
```

drawing each frame on top of a canvas and capturing those frames from it (in the frontend itself)and sending those frames in real-time to the backend using web sockets. I am not sure about this approach as this might be bad for frontend memory wise,

What could be a more efficient way of implementing real-time frame editing with frame manipulation libraries like OpenCV and FFmpeg

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends on what you mean by 'real time'.

If you want to extract a frame, edit and change it, and then display it as close as possible to the time the original frame would have been displayed then you clearly have a very small time budget before you start introducing a noticeable delay.

Sending the stream to a server will add to the delay clearly, but you will likely find that there is already quite a bit of delay in the encoding of the stream and then decoding it to play it back. If this is the case then you are not really working in real time any more and adding some small extra delay to analyse and edit frames may not be significant. You can also reduce the workload analysing and editing by only extracting every nth frame, e.g. every 10th frame, if this will meet your requirements - this can make a significant difference to the workload.